# Given that $x,y,z$ are positive reals such that $xyz=1$.What is the minimum value of $(x^2+4)(y^2+4)(z^2+4)$.

Tags: inequality

Help me to prove that minimum value of expression $ (x^2+4)(y^2+4)(z^2+4) $ is 125 when $ xyz = 1$. I think that minimum value achieved when $x=y=z=1$. But I can prove only $ (x^2+4)(y^2+4)(z^2+4) = xyz(x+\frac{4}{x})(y+\frac{4}{y})(z+\frac{4}{z}) = (x+\frac{4}{x})(y+\frac{4}{y})(z+\frac{4}{z}) \ge 2\sqrt{x \frac{4}{x}} \cdot 2\sqrt{y \frac{4}{y}} \cdot 2\sqrt{z \frac{4}{z}} = 2^6=64$

Comment: Do you know Lagrange method?

Comment: @FormerMath I'll try to use Lagrange method, but I ask for solution without derivatives if it possible

Comment: According to the last inequality, the minimum is $64$

Comment: AMGM (bearing in mind what the equality conditions are) seem to work immediately. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Vasya each multiplier minimum value is 4 but they reach it when x=y=z=2 this is contradicts xyz=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that the (suspected) equality condition is when $ x = y = z = 1 $.

In your inequality, it is achieved only when $ x = \frac{4}{x}$, which gives us $x = 2$. So, your approach likely would not work.

How can we take the equality condition into account? We can weight the variables so that the AM-GM equality condition results in $x=1$.

> $ x^2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 \geq 5 x^{\frac{2}{5} }$, with equality when $ x= 1$.

Answer (score 3):

**A sketch**:

You can expand the product
\begin{align}
(x^2+4)(y^2+4)(z^2+4)&=x^2y^2z^2+4(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)+16(x^2+y^2+z^2)+64\\
&=4(x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2)+16(x^2+y^2+z^2)+65.
\end{align}
Now use the AM-GM inequality: the geometric mean of $x^2,y^2, z^2$ is equal to $1$, so $\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}3\ge 1$, and the minimum is attained when $w=y=z \:(=1)$.

Same observation for $x^2y^2, y^2z^2,z^2x^2$ and therefore
$$(x^2+4)(y^2+4)(z^2+4)\ge 4\cdot 3+16\cdot 3+65=125.$$

Answer (score 0):

By Holder $$(x^4+4)(y^4+4)(z^4+4)\ge {\left(\sqrt[3]{x^4y^4z^4}+\sqrt[3]{4\cdot 4\cdot 4}\right)}^3=125$$